# How to override Django Admin

Tags: python, django, overriding, admin

I have two models Restaurant and Details. The superuser assigns each restaurant a user.When that user logs into admin i want only those Details associated with that user's Restaurant to be shown,and he should be able to edit them as well.
I tried to override admin's queryset function but to no success.Any help would be appreciated. This is what i did so far

I am just a beginner in Django.

```
class RestaurantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Details

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super(RestaurantAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def queryset(self, request):
        print(request.user)
        qs = super(ResaturantAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        # If super-user, show all comments
        if request.user.is_superuser:
          return qs
        return qs.filter(owner=request.user)




admin.site.register(Restaurant)
admin.site.register(Details,RestaurantAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you need to override is called `get_queryset`, not `queryset`.